# Como interromper a consulta ao banco de dados usando time out no hibernate?

Tags: sql, hibernate

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que faz consulta a um banco de dados gigantesco, sendo assim, gostaria de manter a integridade deste permitindo que o Hibernate faça consultas de até no máximo 30 segundos. Diante deste problema, qual seria a melhor forma de resolve-lo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complementando a resposta do Jean, no hibernate você tem o método [.setTimeout()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setTimeout%28int%29) em que você pode definir o tempo máximo em que uma determinada query vai poder executar.

Exemplo:

```
Query suaQuery;
// Tempo do timeout e sua unidade
suaQuery.setTimeout(10,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Caso a query demore mais que o tempo definido irá lançar uma exceção do tipo [QueryTimeoutException](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/QueryTimeoutException.html), que você pode capturar e fazer os tratamentos necessários.

```
try {
    suaQuery.list();
}
catch (QueryTimeoutException e) {
    // faz qualquer tratamento que seja necessário
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu o problema certinho aqui!!

Answer (score 1):

Faz um tempo que fiz isso com nHibernate. Procure por referências às propriedades de conexão no hibernate. No mesmo arquivo/código onde você define a conexão você pode definir o timeout. abaixo alguns exemplos retirados do [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569867/spring-hibernate-session-time-out)

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
```

aqui usando Spring

```
<prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</prop>
```

Comment: Estou fazendo uma consulta nativa SQL usando o SQLQuery, teria algum problema se setasse um setTimeout() para este tipo de query?

Comment: A princípio não, pelo menos nenhum problema diferente pois o timeout em si pode ser considerado um problema dependendo de como vc trata/mitiga isso